# mvn install artifact id missing?

Tags: maven, jar

Hi i am trying to manually install a jar library in my local .m2 mvn repositry using this:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/Users/me/sdk.jar -DgroupId=com.jr.android.sdk \ -DartifactId=sdk -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Doesnt work. i get the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.993 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-04-29T12:24:36+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) on project sdk The artifact information is incomplete or not valid:
[ERROR] [0]  'artifactId' is missing.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Can you post the pom.xml file?

Comment: remove `\` before `-DartifactId`

Comment: What is the backslash `\\` doing in the command?  Can you try without that?

Comment: remvoing the backslash did the trick. i basiclaly copied the example from the maven website which included the backslash http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Answer (score 0):

Backslash removed and fixed it.

The backslash appeared on the maven example: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html